# Android - Adding Effects to Videos like Instagram

Tags: android, opencv, video, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I am in need of a idea to apply filters to video like Instagram, video trimming and fetching images from the video. I have researched a lot and all I can come up with is the following ways to achieve what I want :

1. [FFMPEG](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html)
2. [Open CV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html)
3. [Camera2 API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xtp3tH27OFs)

**FFMPEG :**

As far as FFMPEG is considered, majority of the average level droid devs feel that its a pain cause it involves NDK and compiling the FFMPEG commands.The above mentioned link is self-explanatory and it saves me the pain of setting up the NDK but the biggest drawback in this is that its not stable and its REALLY slow. 
My query on this topic is that how do I compile FFMPEG into my project. I have gone through several links to integrate FFMPEG as follows :

[One](http://jonhall.info/how_to/setup_and_use_ffmpeg_on_windows)

[Two](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows)

[Three](http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/)

The third link seemed to make sense but ultimately I couldn't understand completely and go where,do what after following those steps.

**Question 1 :**

Is there is a solid Android - FFMPEG Integration Document that can help a beginner like me ?

**Open CV**

**Question 2 :**

I haven't tried Open CV yet but will it be worth it ?

**Camera2 API**

**Question 3:**

As far as I researched, I can see that the Camera2 API can help us shoot videos and images with effects added to it but will it be useful for me to process the already existing videos and images ? I don't have the requirement to add effects to the camera while its captured, its aftermath is where I want to add my effects.

If someone is kind enough to accept my stupidity and help me out, I am thankful to them.

Will going ahead with FFMPEG be good or OpenCV or Camera2 API will be better ?

Comment: Requests for libraries and tutorials are off topic